# Authenticity Of Narration In Tabaqat Al-Kubra That Says That Jesus Is Dead And He Will Not Return To Earth

Tags: authenticity

I found a narration in  Tabaqat  Al-Kubra that says that Holy Prophet Jesus is allegedly dead and he will not return. The following is the English translation of the narration, **so I am not sure if I am accurately translating it** (Please see the original screenshot of the Arabic narration).

Here is the English translation:-

Imam Hasan (Radhi'allahu'anhu) used to say about the death of Ali (Radhi'allahu'anhu): O people! Today such a person has died and no person has ever attained the status of Ali (Radhi'alluhu'anhu) before and no person can ever attain his status. Whenever Rasulullah (Sallallahu'alayhiwassalam) used to send Ali (Radhi'allahu'anhu) to fight in a battle, angel Gabriel used to accompany Ali (Radhi'allahu'anhu) in his right side and angel Mikail used to accompany him at his left side. Hence, he always came back after being victorious over his enemies. He left behind 700 Dirhams and he wished to purchase a slave from that money. **Ali (Radhi'allahu'anhu) died on the night of 27th of Ramadan. This was the same night when Jesus' soul was raised up into the heavens** ***( Tabaqat  Al-Kubra, volume 1, page no.28)***

**The main question is: what is the authenticity of this narration?**

Here is the screenshot of the narration in the original Arabic language. However, I am not sure about the authenticity of this narration (I am sorry for poor picture quality):-

https://books.google.com.pk/books?id=2O5ICwAAQBAJ&pg=PT31#v=onepage&q&f=false

[image]

Comment: The screenshot is terrible. But, even in the translation what part of it exactly proves Jesus (AS) won't return?

Comment: Couldn't find this anywhere in Khasais al-Kubra. It is however in [Tabaqat Al-Kubra](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1686/696).

Comment: And the implication that has been derived is not adequately proven from the actual wording. Rather it simply means that Ali was martyred the night on which Jesus was raised to the heavens. Compare it with the version that is narrated by [Tabari](https://al-maktaba.org/book/9783/2619#p1) ( وفيها رفع عيسى بن مريم) and [Mustadrak al-Hakim](https://al-maktaba.org/book/2266/4978) (وليلة أسري بعيسى)

Comment: What is al_Khassais al-Kubra and who is the author?

Comment: @ياsr Al-Khassais al-Kubra [الخصائص الكبرى](https://al-maktaba.org/book/6590) is in fact a book of imam as-Suyuti which basically could fit in the context, but I couldn't find this narration there however it is in ibn Sa'ad's at-Tabaqaat al-Kubra and without the additional sentence about 'Isa ibn Maryam in many other references. See also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Khasais-ul-Kubra)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reliability of some of the transmitters is disputed such as that of  [أجلح بن عبد الله الكندي](https://islamic-content.com/rawi/399) who is considered weak by a group of imams such as Nisai, Abu Hatim al-Razi, Ahmad ibn Hanbal, Abu Dawud and others. While some of the other transmitters have also been criticized.

This narration:

1. does not evidence that Jesus عليه السلام will not return to earth. That claim depends on the assertion that if he died then he can not return, which is false. Various people have been resurrected and returned to the earth after their death as evident in the Quran in [2:259](https://quran.com/2/259?translations=20), [2:243](https://quran.com/2/243?translations=20), [2:73](https://quran.com/2/73?translations=20), [2:56](https://quran.com/2/56?translations=20).
2. does not evidence that Jesus died, at least not clearly. If the soul of Jesus ascended ( عُرِجَ ) that does not imply that he had died as the soul may travel without death. It is in the Quran in [6:60](https://quran.com/6/60?translations=20) and [39:42](https://quran.com/39/42?translations=20) that it happens during sleep without death. Also it is the madhab of a group that Prophet Muhammad's ﷺ soul ascended to heaven during the Mi’raaj, yet that does not mean that he died.

Even the existence of the word روح (spirit) in the original saying is disputable, as there are at least three chains of transmission which omit it:

- > في ليلة نزل فيها القرآن، وفيها **رفع عيسى ابن مريم**، وفيها قتل يوشع بن نون فتى موسى
  >
  > In the night in which the Quran was revealed, and in it **Jesus son of Mary was raised**, and in it Joshua son of Nun was killed who was the servant (and successor) of Moses
  >
  > <sup>— [Musnad Abu Ya'la](https://al-maktaba.org/book/32852/6775)</sup>

  This has been classed as [saheeh](https://ia801307.us.archive.org/0/items/WAQ3580/mayala12.pdf#page=125) or [hasan](https://ia802304.us.archive.org/17/items/FPmazmt/mazmt18.pdf#page=238). Its transmitters include the ahl al-bayt such as Jafar al-Sadiq, Muhammad al-Baqir and Zayn al-Abidin.
- > قتل ليلة أنزل القرآن، وليلة **أسري بعيسى**، وليلة قبض موسى
  >
  > on which the Quran was revealed, and the night **Jesus traveled**, and the night when Moses died
  >
  > <sup>— [Mustadrak al-Hakim](https://al-maktaba.org/book/2266/4978)</sup>

  All the transmitters are thiqa except الحريث بن مخشي who seems to be less known but is thiqa according to Ibn Hibban.
- > الليلة التي **عرج فيها عيسى بن مريم**، ليلة سبع وعشرين من رمضان
  >
  > in the night on which Jesus ascended, the 27th night of Ramadan
  >
  > <sup>— [Mu'jam al-Kabir Tabarani](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1733/3251)</sup>

  This chain has an overlap with that of Tabaqat Al-Kubra and so has at least the same weakness.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. But some narrators in the Tabaqat Al-Kubra's narration can be found in Sahiayn and other Sihah Sitta books.

Comment: @UmH- For example,

Abdullah bin Numa'air can be found in Sahih Muslim 1627b and Sahih Al-Bukhari 2591 (See Sunnah.com)

Abi Ishaq is obviously one of the reliable narrators and he can be found in various places in the Sahihayn.

Comment: Hubairah bin Yareemah cannot be found in the Sahihayn but he can be found in other collections of hadith like Jami' Tirmidhi, Sunan Ibn Majah, etc. In the online hadith Encyclopedia, it has been stated that Imam Ahmad bin Hanbal and Dhahabi have classified Hubairah bin Yareemah as thiqa. However, only Yahya bin Ma'yeen classified him as Majh'ul (Unknown). [Source: Encyclopedia of Hadith; Web Source: Hadith.Islam-db.com]

Comment: The chain of link between Ibn Ishaq and Hubairah bin Yareemah can also be found in Musnad Ahmad 1115 and Jami' Tirmidhi 795. (Source: Sunnah.com)

Comment: Ajlah Al-Kindi was classified as trustworthy by Yahyah bin Ma'en and Yaqub Al-Faswai. However, this chain of narrators might not be acceptable according to Yahyah as this chain has Hubairah bin Yareemah. So yes, this chain of narrators might be disputable.

Comment: Isn't أجلح بن عبد الله الكندي considered acceptabe by Ibn Hajr Asqalani?

Comment: Also you have not explained what is the problem with other narrators in this narration. I would really appreciate if you can point that out, too Thanks.